# $A$ is unitary iff $\langle Av,Av\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle$ over arbitrary field

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, unitary-matrices

I am trying to show that $A$ is unitary iff $\langle Av,Av\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle$ when $A$ comes from an *arbitrary* field. That is, we are dealing with an arbitrary inner product space, so we only have the basic axioms of inner products (positive definiteness, conjugate symmetry, and linearity) at our disposal. That said, I'm not sure if we are able to use $\langle v,Aw\rangle=\langle A^*v,w\rangle$ since I don't know how to prove this without $\langle v,w\rangle=w^*v$ defined over $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$. Any hints?

Comment: What's the definition of a unitary matrix over a field that's not $\mathbb C$?

Comment: $\langle v,Aw\rangle=\langle A^*v,w\rangle$ is basically the definition of $A^*$; the only thing missing is a $\forall v, w$.

Comment: Why does the definition need to be restricted to $\mathbb{C}$? Can't we just say $A\in\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ is unitary if $A^*A=AA^*=\mathbb{I}_n$?

Comment: Well, what I mean when I say $A^*$ is "the conjugate transpose of $A$", which makes no sense over an arbitrary field.

Comment: For that matter, inner product spaces are usually restricted to being over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. At the minimum we need an **ordered** field for $\langle v, v\rangle \ge 0$ to hold. Also, for symmetry or conjugate symmetry, we need to (once again) say what "conjugate" means.

Comment: Here is an attempt to define these things: Let $E/F$ be a degree 2 field extension. Define conjugation as the non-identity element of the Galois group. Define inner product for $a,b \in E^n$ as $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i^*$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you all.